# Visual C# - How do I write text to a Word Document Template?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Working on a program involving taking the names and addresses of various people and printing them onto a 3x10 label sheet.  The one in question is the WL-875 template [here](http://www.worldlabel.com/Templates/wl-ol875Word.htm).  The code I have written to try and get it to work is below (I am kinda shooting in the dark, as I've never done this before, so it is incomplete).  What code is there where I can set up a loop where I mark a spot in the template to add to, add the necessary information, and then move down to the next one as long as there are labels in the label queue?

If I'm getting details wrong or anything, like I said, I'm completely clueless on what to do from here, or even if I'm doing it right.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Reflection;

public Print(LabelQueue queue, User a)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */

        //Start Word and create a new document.
        Word._Application oWord;
        Word._Document oDoc;
        oWord = new Word.Application();
        oWord.Visible = false;
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

        // Declare a template and add to word document
        object oTemplate = "c:\\GitHub\iD2015\PO\Resources\MyTemplate.dotx";
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

     }
```

Comment: What kind of application is this?  If you're coding for a server-side application, you should avoid using Office automation of any sort.  Client-side it should be fine to use it.

Comment: have you tried any google searches.. here is a link that looks similar to what you are trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294084/change-or-add-template-in-word-document

Answer (score 0):

MailMerge is designed for this type of thing.  Here's a link that should at least get you started with it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301659